# Programmatically setting the translucent theme at runtime

Tags: android, android-theme

In my application, I want to make screen translucent at runtime on a click of a button.
I tried

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

in the `onClick()` method, but it did not work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29 `Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set theme before views are instantiated as @Selvin said. To do that, I restarted my activity on click of my button with some different theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the activity theme to translucent in the manifest and in the main layout of the activity set a background, when you click the button just remove the layout background or set it to transparent.